# Hammer.js TypeError: element is null, using inside $(document).ready:

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I'm trying to get the problem around this: using inside a block like this

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... } )
```

a function for initialize Hammer.js, like so:

```
    var area = document.querySelector('#keyboard');
    var hammertime = new Hammer(area);

    hammertime.on("pan", { /* options */ }, function(eventu) {
        console.log("pan"); 
    }); 
    hammertime.on("tap", { /* options */ }, function(eventu) {
        console.log("tap!"); 
    });
```

When it is just called, this generates:

> TypeError: element is null

and it links to this function inside hammer.js code:

```
- element.addEventListener(type, handler,
> false);
```

How should call correctly that? I'm really in stuck for this, jQuery ready seems not the right way... I tried also to move code inside a block like:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
//here thecode above
}, false);
```

but I get same error.

[edit] In all Hammer.js examples they use to work on DIVs element, here I'm trying doing this on li(st) ones, should be this related to my problem?

I.e:

```
<ul id="keyboard">
<li id="first">...</li>
<li id="second">...</li>
[...]
</ul>
```

and then:

```
var area = document.querySelector('#keyboard');
```

or (same problem):

```
var area = document.querySelector('#first');
```

Any ideas? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var area = document.querySelector('#keyboard');
```

In native JS, you don't need to add the `#` or `.` to an ID or class, respectively. Just the name.

I think if you removes the #, the element will be found.

Comment: thanks, I tried but does not work, besides in the official documentation ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector ) they say to put . and # for referring CSS selector.
I added some details to question, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved, anyway I had the same issue today and discovered what follows.
It seems that, beside what is stated on Hammer.js website, when creating a new Hammer instance with the default statement:

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(area)
```

it doesn't have default input event recognizers.
So you can try to add those you want in this way:

```
var hammertime = new Hammer.Manager(area, {
          recognizers: [
            [Hammer.Pan, {enable: true}],
            [Hammer.Tap, {enable: true}]
          ]
        });
```

This has solved for me. 
You can find more options and details on the Hammer.js website, in particular:
http://hammerjs.github.io/api/#hammer.manager
http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-pan/
http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-tap/